# How can i correct or interpret a negative but an insignificant error correction term?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, eviews

The variables that are used for cointegration are I(1). I got the error correction term as negative but it not significant. So how should i proceed for the results?

Comment: What is the goal of your analysis? See also [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217424/), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203649/) and maybe some related questions; I have answered a few of these.

Comment: thank you for the response. The goal is to check if there's any co-integration among the variables and if yes then it's Error correction model.

Comment: *The goal is to check if there's any co-integration among the variables*. Then use a test, e.g. Johansen test or Engle-Granger test. (Why do you care about a negative error correction term if it does not answer the question of whether there is cointegration or not?)